Passing a value from one dataset to another dataset in SSRS - avoiding performance impact
I have an SSRS Report for the Dynamics platform using FetchXML.

Using the "enableprefilter" in the entity tag (assign it a value of 1), I grab the GUID of whatever record is in view, and store it in a parameter.
I then use that parameter to filter for the record I want.

For the 2nd dataset, I find I can't reuse the parameter from above, instead, I must create another parameter, and use the "Get values from a query" option, where I refer to the 1st dataset. There is a warning next to this option that says "Warning Possible performance impact", however, I don't know any other way to get the value from the 1st dataset - is this the only solution?
